# How to replace alphanumeric values in string in iOS?

Tags: ios, string, swift, str-replace, masking

I want to replace all alphanumeric characters except white spaces in a string in iOS. Any compact solution?

This is my recent approach:

```
var strIn = "apple banana mushroom"
let a = (strIn).componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

var strReturn: NSString
for str in a {

    let str3 = "".stringByPaddingToLength((str as NSString).length, withString: "*", startingAtIndex: 0)
    strReturn = strReturn.stringByAppendingString(str3)
}
```

expected result is: `"****** ****** ********"`

Comment: what is you expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple version could be something like that:

```
let strIn = "apple banana mushroom"
let words = strIn.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

var starred: [String] = []

for word in words {
    let stars = Array(count: word.characters.count, repeatedValue: "*").joinWithSeparator("")
    starred.append(stars)
}

let result = starred.joinWithSeparator(" ")
```

Result:

> "***** ****** ********"

You can make it an extension for easier usage:

```
extension String {
    var stars:String {
        let words = self.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        var starred: [String] = []
        for word in words {
            let stars = Array(count: word.characters.count, repeatedValue: "*").joinWithSeparator("")
            starred.append(stars)
        }
        return starred.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    }
}

let starred = "apple banana mushroom".stars
```

You can also replace the loop with `map` and produce some kind of monster one-liner. It's efficient but not very readable, so use at your own discretion:

```
extension String {
    var stars:String {
        return self.componentsSeparatedByString(" ").map { Array(count: $0.characters.count, repeatedValue: "*").joinWithSeparator("") }.joinWithSeparator(" ")
    }
}

let starred = "apple banana mushroom".stars
```

Comment: The `map` version is not readable because you are doing operations you don't need :)

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, because this `map` version is the reduction of the previous loop version. I could have refactored indeed. :) // I just had a look at the second part of your answer: congrats for being so concise. Upvoted. :) I still like my version though, it's a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to split the string into Array, and then again append all array into a full string.

You can do it easily:

```
var strIn = "apple banana mushroom"

for tempChar in strIn.unicodeScalars {
   if tempChar != " "{
      strIn = strIn.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(String(tempChar), withString: "*")
   }
}

Result:***** ****** ********
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is using a regular expression:

```
let strIn = "apple banana mushroom"

// reg exp matching everything that is not a whitespace character
let regExp = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^\\s]", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions())
let strOut = regExp.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(
    strIn,
    options: NSMatchingOptions(),
    range: NSMakeRange(0, strIn.characters.count),
    withTemplate: "*"
)

print("\(strOut)")
```

There is also a simple version using `String.characters.map`:

```
let mappedChars = strIn.characters.map({ $0 == " " ? $0 : "*" })
let strOut = String(mappedChars)
print("\(strOut)")
```

(you can replace the `==` by any more complicated check or even a function if you want to add different whitespace chars)

If you also want to replace multiple spaces with a single space, I would advise you to do it separately.

Answer (score -1):

You can use NSRegularExpression.

```
NSString *string = @"apple banana mushroom";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regularEx = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *newString = [regularEx stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"*"];
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

Now you can add any pattern to NSRegularExpression like regex pattern.

Answer in Swift 1.2:

```
var myString = "apple banana mushroom"
var error: NSError?
let internalExpression = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[a-z][0-9]*", options: .CaseInsensitive, error: &error)
if (!error){
 let replacedString = internalExpression .stringByReplacingMatchesInString(myString, options: NSMatchingOptions.fromMask(0), range: NSMakeRange(0, countElements(myString)), withTemplate: "*")
}
```

Comment: The code is actually better than other answers although you could improve your regular expression a lot (using `[a-zA-Z0-9]` pattern or just `[^\s]`). Still, you should translate it to Swift (which is trivial).

Comment: @sulthan: the expression is caseInsensitive so doesnot require A-Z.